# Tomcat started but webpage not coming up in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I have downloaded and extracted tomcat in my unix machine and also able to start tomcat using below command

```
sh startup.sh
```

and getting this response

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

I have added java and catalina home in bashrc file

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
```

but when i hit the "ip:8080" the page is showing This site can’t be reached

I have treid multiple solution but getting nothing worked for me

Comment: I'd start by checking if the process is running.  Next, because you're showing an installation in `/opt`, does the user running Tomcat have permission to write to the `/opt/tomcat` directory?  If so, check in `/opt/tomcat/logs` directory to see if there are any errors.

Comment: not gettng any error\